# Linq to XML not getting all nodes

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OrdersReport Date="2012-08-01">
<Returns>
      <Amount>
        <OrderId>2</OrderId>
        <OrderId>3</OrderId>
        <OrderId>21</OrderId>
        <OrderId>23</OrderId>
      </Amount>
    </Returns>
</OrdersReport>
```

This is the code I am trying to get OrderId:

```
 var amount = doc.Descendants("Amount")                         
  .Select(y => new
  {
   OrderId = (int)y.Element("OrderId")
   });
foreach (var r in amount)
  {
   Console.WriteLine(r.OrderId);
  }

 Console.Read();
```

My output is:

```
2
2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the info undersand this properly

[**XContainer.Descendants Method (XName)**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx) - Returns a filtered collection of the descendant elements for this document or element, in document order. Only elements that have a matching XName are included in the collection.

so in your code

```
var amount = doc.Descendants("Amount")                         
  .Select(y => new
  {
   OrderId = (int)y.Element("OrderId")
   });
```

this will give you Element `Amount` and when you write `y.Element("OrderId")` will return you fist element of its child.

so to get all OrderID Elements you need either to write down `doc.Descendants("OrderId")` or `documentRoot.Descendants("Amount").Descendants()`

`Descendants` - doesnt mean than its return the child element of element name you writtne in desendant method.

---

Finally following solution work for me in proper way

```
XElement documentRoot  = XElement.Parse (@"<OrdersReport Date='2012-08-01'>
                                                  <Returns>
                                                      <Amount>
                                                             <OrderId>21</OrderId>
                                                             <OrderId>3</OrderId>
                                                        </Amount>
                                                </Returns>
                                                </OrdersReport>");

           var orderids = from order in
                             documentRoot.Descendants("Amount").Descendants()
                          select new
                          {
                              OrderId = order.Value
                          };
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
var orderIds = doc.Descendants("OrderId");
foreach (var orderId in orderIds)
{
    Console.WriteLine(orderId.Value);
}
```

Or, which in this case will be the same:

```
var orders = doc.Descendants("Amount")
                .Descendants("OrderId");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var orderIds = doc.Descendants("OrderId")
                  .Select(e => e.Value)
                  .ToArray();
```

The result will be:

```
[2, 3, 21, 23]
```